# Contar elementos entre duas grandezas

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Estou criando uma *dashboard* demográfica para uma organização religiosa, onde constará a faixa etária de seus membros entre outros dados.

As idades de inscrição e promoção entre suas classes de educação religiosa serão usadas como critério.

Então:

```
0 a 10 anos
11 a 17 anos
18 a 35 anos
36 a 50 anos
50 anos ou mais
```

Na planilha com os dados demográficos criei uma tabela chamada **`RolDeMembros`**, sua coluna `Idade` retorna por linha o resultado da fórmula abaixo:

```
=CONCATENAR(SOMA(ANO(HOJE())-ANO([@[Dt. Nasc.]]));" anos")
```

[image: Tabela criada na planilha Rol de Membros com a coluna Idade mostrando a fórmula descrita acima]

Numa terceira planilha eu mantenho os dados demográficos consolidados.

Nas faixas etárias, tentei usar **`=CONT.SE()`** para calcular cada uma das faixas, mas não estou recebendo os dados esperados. Para cada faixa, estou usando o seguinte:

```
=CONT.SE(RolDeMembros[Idade];"<=10")
=CONT.SE(RolDeMembros[Idade];">=11<=17")
=CONT.SE(RolDeMembros[Idade];">=18<=35")
=CONT.SE(RolDeMembros[Idade];">=36<=50")
=CONT.SE(RolDeMembros[Idade];">=51")
```

O resultado que obtenho é o seguinte:

[image: Resultado totalmente errado das fórmulas]

O que está totalmente errado. 169 é a quantidade de membros da organização, os maiores de 50 anos contam 62 e assim por diante. Tudo errado.

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Sua pergunta não está totalmente clara porque faltam detalhes importantes. Como você criou a tabela `RolDeMembros`? Pela fórmula que você publicou, eu fui levado a entender que essa tabela tem, por exemplo,  o conteúdo `32 anos`. Se for isso, comparações do tipo `"<=35"` não irão funcionar porque esperam um campo numérico. Fornece exemplos da tabela, se possível inclua capturas de imagem da planilha.

Comment: Obrigado por seu comentário. A tabela foi criada selecionando-se o intervalo de dados da planilha Rol de Membros, incluindo seus cabeçalhos, e usando o comando Tabela da guia Inserir; em seguida, na guia Design, nomeei a tabela como RolDeMembros. Sobre a fórmula, por causa da função CONCATENAR() ela retorna, por exemplo, 32 anos. Retirei a função e ainda assim não deu o resultado esperado. Quanto a prints, refarei a planilha à parte, por motivos contratuais e editarei a pergunta.

Comment: @LuizVieira, coloquei duas screenshots, espero que ajudem a entender a situação.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, veja se te atende.

Answer (score 2):

O seu projeto tem dois erros.

### Problema 1

Como já te responderam, você não pode utilizar mais de um critério de comparação na função `CONT.SE`. Para isso, você **precisa** utilizar a função `CONT.SES` (que permite adicionar vários intervalos e critérios). No seu caso o intervalo é o mesmo, então você repete, e só adiciona o "novo" critério. Assim, o que você imaginou como:

```
=CONT.SE(RolDeMembros[Idade];">=11<=17")
```

Fica como:

```
=CONT.SES(RolDeMembros[Idade];">=11";RolDeMembros[Idade];"<=17")
```

### Problema 2

O problema 1 já havia sido respondido por outros colegas, mas eu aposto que ainda assim não funcionou pra você. É que ainda resta o problema (que eu [já havia comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165281/contar-elementos-entre-duas-grandezas#comment339763_165281)) de que os dados na sua coluna "Idade" **não são numéricos**. A função que você usa pra montar essa coluna é:

```
=CONCATENAR(SOMA(ANO(HOJE())-ANO([@[Dt. Nasc.]]));" anos")
```

E o problema tá justamente no fato de que ela monta uma string (do tipo `"35 anos"`) e retorna na coluna. Logo, a coluna contém *texto* e não números. Por isso a sua comparação não funciona. O ideal é você manter nessa coluna só os números mesmo. O que é simples, basta alterar a sua função acima para:

```
=SOMA(ANO(HOJE())-ANO([@[Dt. Nasc.]]))
```

O "problema" de não exibir para o usuário o texto "anos" na frente é simples de ser resolvido na formatação. Acesse a formatação das células (botão direito, escolha "Formatar células"), vá em formatação personalizada, e digite `00 "anos"`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pronto! Assim as fórmulas usando `CONT.SES` vão funcionar corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: obrigado por sua resposta. Depois de seu comentário à minha pergunta, [disse que havia retirado a função CONCATENAR() sem, no entanto, ter o resultado esperado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165281/contar-elementos-entre-duas-grandezas#comment339768_165281). E desde as respostas eu tenho usado a função CONT.SES() para todas as faixas excepto a primeira, sem ainda ter o resultado esperado Vou tentar as respostas atualizadas. Novamente, obrigado..

Comment: Por nada. Mas se não funcionou com a coluna com valores numéricos, você tem algum outro errinho por aí. Talvez valha a pena uma revisada geral ou até mesmo reescrever a fórmula.

Answer (score 0):

Certo, como há texto em sua fórmula, ideal será criar uma nova coluna com somente os números (idades) para que seja criado o quadro desejado.

A partir daí use as seguintes fórmulas:

```
=CONT.SE(RolDeMembros[Idade];"<"&11)
=CONT.SES(RolDeMembros[Idade];">="&11;RolDeMembros[Idade];"<"&18)
=CONT.SES(RolDeMembros[Idade];">="&18;RolDeMembros[Idade];"<"&36)
=CONT.SES(RolDeMembros[Idade];">="&36;RolDeMembros[Idade];"<"&51)
=CONT.SE(RolDeMembros[Idade];">="&51)
```

Pode-se usar o número junto conforme fez *"<="*, contudo utilizei o **&** (E comercial) para que possa ter uma tabela de faixa etária.

Veja esse exemplo:

https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/CONT-SES-Fun%25C3%25A7%25C3%25A3o-CONT-SES-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842?ui=pt-BR&rs=pt-BR&ad=BR&fromAR=1

Utilizei algo parecido nessa planilha com a faixa de preço da CAESB (Serviço de fornecimento de água do DF).

https://github.com/excelguru/compara_valor_agua

Outra coisa que pode utilizar é o tipo de fórmula para cálculo da idade, veja alguns exemplos mais comuns disponibilizados pela Microsoft:

https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Calcular-idade-113d599f-5fea-448f-a4c3-268927911b37?ui=pt-BR&rs=pt-BR&ad=BR&fromAR=1

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta. Precisei editar sua fórmula para `=CONT.SES(RolDeMembros[Idade];">="&11;RolDeMembros[Idade];"<="&17)` e seguintes, mas não funcionou. Eu já havia lido esse artigo de suporte, mas sem sucesso também. Vou estudar a planilha que linkou para ver se encontro uma solução.

Comment: @JoaoSantana Isso mesmo, desculpe-me, não estou com Excel nesta máquinha então não pude testar. Abraço boa sorte ai.

Answer (score 0):

Para tratar os dados alfanuméricos apresenados na planilha, substitua "idade" por:

```
ESQUERDA(idade;PROCURAR(" ";idade)-1)
```

Esta fórmula tira o texto " anos" e somente a parte numérica da idade será considerada.

As fórmulas ficariam assim no meu exemplo, para os dados alfanuméricos que está usando para idade.

```
=CONT.SE(ESQUERDA(Idade;PROCURAR(" ";Idade)-1);"<=10")
=CONT.SES(ESQUERDA(Idade;PROCURAR(" ";Idade)-1);">=11";ESQUERDA(Idade;PROCURAR(" ";Idade)-1);"<18")
=CONT.SES(ESQUERDA(Idade;PROCURAR(" ";Idade)-1);">=18";ESQUERDA(Idade;PROCURAR(" ";Idade)-1);"<35")
=CONT.SES(ESQUERDA(Idade;PROCURAR(" ";Idade)-1);">=36";ESQUERDA(Idade;PROCURAR(" ";Idade)-1);"<50")
=CONT.SE(ESQUERDA(Idade;PROCURAR(" ";Idade)-1);">=51")
```

Basta adaptar suas fórmulas para aplicar na tabela.

O exemplo abaixo é sem aplicação de tabela e com dados numéricos para as idades:

Selecione a coluna com as idades, e na parte superior esquerda do **Excel**, onde aparece o endereço da célula ativa (coluna e linha, por exemplo, B22), escreva o nome da coluna: **Idade**

Fiz isso para os dados abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em outra **ABA** coloque as seguintes fórmulas, que no exemplo abaixo já apresentam o resultado à direita delas:

```
=CONT.SE(Idade;"<=10")                    10
=CONT.SES(Idade;">=11";Idade;"<18")        7
=CONT.SES(Idade;">=18";Idade;"<35")       17
=CONT.SES(Idade;">=36";Idade;"<50")       14
=CONT.SE(Idade;">=51")                    10
```

Repare que ao nomear a faixa de dados (igual à coluna selecionada neste caso), o **Excel** entende inclusive a que **ABA** eles pertencem.

Caso o termo "planilha" indique que está usando arquivos distintos (**XLSX**), é só adaptar o que apresentei.

É isso.

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta, @Leo. Quando falo em _planilha_, estou me referindo às _planilhas na mesma pasta de trabalho_, que na sua resposta você chama de aba. Quanto ao procedimento que descreve, ao se criar uma tabela, seus cabeçalhos são nomeados e podem ser referenciados do mesmo jeito, como inclusive escrevi na pergunta. Repeti, por fim, a estrutura que descreveu mas, ainda assim, me retorna `0`; Poderia me passar a planilha onde obteve esse resultado, para comparação?

Comment: Oi @João, legal, a planilha tem exatamente o que está descrito na resposta, usei duas ABAS para isso (com ABA fica mais claro para mim que se trata do mesmo arquivo, ou no meu caso, da mesma planilha, mas é o hábito), a primeira com as fórmulas e a segunda com os números em coluna nomeada e iniciando do valor 1 na linha 1. Caso não consiga, retorne.

Comment: @João, editei minha resposta com que acredito resolverá teu problema sem alterar tua tabela de dados.

Comment: OI @JoãoSantana, voltei a editar a resposta, havia uma parte desnecessária na última linha da última fórmula que não havia reparado quando postei, tanto na parte inicial para dados alfanuméricos como na parte anterior que mantive, mas a funcionalidade estava correta. Alguma das respostas aqui te ajudou ou encaminhou para a solução do problema? Se sim, por favor, marque a resposta.com o "check" abaixo da pontuação desta resposta. Bom trabalho.